# Neural Network Error oscillating with each epochs, what is the acceptable margin for that?

Tags: tensorflow, validation, loss

I have a multi input/output ANN, I  have trained it for 1000 to 3000 ephocs but with each epochs the validation error oscilate.
For example my output feature is in (mm) and the error can osiclate around 4 mm.
You can see the validation loss vs epochs curve here. My question is how much oscilation is normal or there is something wrong some where in my model?
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ghazalemir/q/blob/main/Curve.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0qTO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fluctuation depends on your validation sample size. The lower size - the higher oscillation. Normal size is 5000 samples.

Comment: Dear Andrey, I have a 12800 data point on my validation set which is 20% of my training set.